# Android: Unable to get data from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I am trying to get a string value in onActivityForResult() from Intent value.

This is how I passed the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("state", getResources().getString(R.string.intent_skip_pin_setup));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

Now I'm getting the "state" as follows:

```
intent_get.getStringExtra("state")
```

but I'm getting null. Is this because I am not using `startActivity(intent)`. I don't want to redirect as the View I wanted is in the background.

This is how im checking:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("state") != null) {
        if ((getIntent().getExtras().getString("state").equals("save_pin_setup") || getIntent().getExtras().getString("state").equals("skip_pin_setup"))) {
            doLaunchDashboard();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to save and fetch data like we do using Intent or Bundle.. as I am not starting the activity, i dont think i can use them (intent/bundle).

Comment: Can You provide more code? I don't get the idea behind this scenario.

Comment: @Adithya.K what you are trying to achive ? onActivityForResult is designed to pass data from one activity to another one. If you are not startingActivity with Intent which you created it will not get it. In this case use other mechanism to share date between activities. Maybe broadcast will suit you needs.

Answer (score 0):

use `intent_get.getExtras().getString("state")`

But before that check if `intent_get` and `intent_get.getExtras()` isn't null. (checks around intent extras can be pretty wild)

Comment: Getting:  ERROR Intent was NULL, app crashing!